Refused entry stamp (c) in Paris. Will it create problems?
Recently, I went from Turkey to Paris to Mexico but mexico denied me entry. They didn't give me any reason. After that they sent me back to Paris but Paris put a stamp on my passport. They put me in a detention center and sent me back to my country.
So I'm worried about it. Can I  transit again in Paris or will this stamp create problems for me?
I am from india and I have my UK C unaccompanied child visit multiple-entry visa.

To answer we need more information and more clarity.  What is your citizenship and country of residence? Was your itinerary Turkey>Mexico > France>Mexico? What visa(s) did you have, if any?

I am from india and i have my uk c child visit unaccompanied multiple entry visa

@Traveller I believe it was Turkey -> France (transit) -> Mexico (refused) -> France (refused) -> wherever.

I suppose you had an Airport Transit Visa for the initial trip from Turkey to Mexico via France?

Yeah like if we india to paris and paris to mexico then we need a transit visa but if we to turkey to paris and paris to mexico then we don't need a transit visa

@JasbirMalik the itinerary has no bearing on the need for an airport transit visa; it depends only on your citizenship and on whether you have a visa or residence permit that exempts you from the requirement.

@jcaron That makes sense. Not sure where the OP’s aborted trip to the UK (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/189008/i-was-denied-entry-in-the-uk-is-my-visa-cancelled) fits into what seems a pretty complicated travel history for a minor…

@Traveller That link says OP chose to disembark on 23.04.2024, this stamp above shows 29.03.2024. So the Mexico and Paris entry refusals happened before UK.

@ave Yes, the order in which the OP posted their questions wasn’t helpful. Conclusion: the OP’s unused UK visa was the/a reason for the Mexican entry denial.

@Traveller I'm not convinced it's just that: From what I've heard from Turkish people, Mexico has been erring on the side of rejecting tourists from there that they suspect may be coming to Mexico to illegally pass to the US. I suspect the itinerary of India?->Turkey->France->Mexico may have raised some concerns.

You're right they are very very strict for indian people even if you have a visa and every document


Refused entry stamp (c) paris will it create problem?

You were refused entry into the Schengen Area because you had no valid visa or residence permit after being refused entry into Mexico.
For the Schengen authorities this is nothing more than that a 3rd county national (that requires a visa to enter the Schengen Area) is returning to their home country.
Had you had, after your refusal of entry into Mexico, an airline ticket back to your home country (understandably unlikely), then there wouldn't have been any need do go through a Schengen passport control at all.
France, however, does require an airport transit visa for Indian citizens:

Airport Transit - France-Visas

Thus (other than the inconvincence of getting a ticket to your home county from the airside portion of the airport) you were allowed to return to your home country.
For a future application for Schengen Visa, this should pose no problem. Based on what you have written, there was no deceitful attempt to enter the Schengen area.
It may be wise to meantion, in the first application, that a refused of entry did occur.

Sources:

Schengen Border Code ANNEX V Part B for full list of reasons

(c) has no valid visa or residence permit




The "(c)" means that you were refused entry to France for the lack of visa (see the Annex V parts A and part B of the Schengen border code).
Since on your way from Mexico you were sent back to France while not having a Schengen visa, the French denied your entry and forwarded you onward to where you came from.
You cannot travel to France (or Schengen) without a valid visa while holding an Indian passport. Indian passport holders also require an Airport Transit Visa for transit through France.


can I take transit again to Paris?

No. You cannot transit or enter France without the appropriate visa. As an Indian citizen, your UK Visitor visa is not valid for Schengen.

will this stamp create a problem for me?

It could, yes. You will have to disclose the denial of entry in any future visa applications that ask about your travel / immigration history.
Note: AFAIK Mexico does allow entry for visa nationals who hold a valid multiple entry visa for the UK. If they denied you entry my guess is you did not fulfil other entry criteria, or perhaps they do not accept the type of UK visa you hold.

Probably for the same reason the OP was denied entry to the UK, or maybe because of that.

@littleadv Indeed, judging by the OP’s recent travel calamities it would be advisable to thoroughly check entry requirements before travelling again

No uk didn't checked that stamp

@JasbirMalik Your two questions indicate you’re bouncing around the globe on the back of having a Child Visitor visa for the UK. You’re starting to rack up what could turn into a hugely disadvantageous immigration history (two entry denials, plus a close shave in the UK). That is not a typical travel pattern, especially for a minor travelling alone.

I am only travelling to the countries where i can go only with my child visitor visa

@JasbirMalik Indeed, however your UK Child Visitor visa does not guarantee you entry to any country, as you’ve discovered recently. More so, when not even the UK gave you permission to enter because you had not paid close attention to the rules pertaining to your visa. Visa-issuing authorities and border officials like to see visitors who have a record of adhering to the relevant rules. Inadvertently, it seems you’ve created the appearance of the exact opposite. You might even have a hard time entering the UK next time given your other entry denials.

From what I've heard from Turkish people, Mexico has been erring on the side of rejecting tourists from there that they suspect may be coming to Mexico to illegally pass to the US. I suspect the itinerary of India?->Turkey->France->Mexico may have raised some concerns.

Should i make a new passport then ??

@JasbirMalik The rules of TSE require users to post new questions separately, not as comments on an existing question. Having said that, getting a new passport would likely be useless - you would have to travel with your old passport with your UK visa in it, so officials would be able to see your immigration mishaps.
